# How to read Alain Connes's Noncommutative Geometry

Tags: learning, quantum-field-theory, noncommutative-geometry

I'm a undergraduate student interested in noncommutative geometry and quantum field theory. And I have learned basic functional analysis,theoretical mechanics,basic quantum mechanics, now, I'm learning classical field theory and quantum field theory.There are two books on this page http://www.alainconnes.org/en/downloads.php [enter link description here](https://www.alainconnes.org/en/downloads.php),Noncommutative Geometry and Noncommutative Geometry, Quantum Fields and Motives.How to read these books,and which papers should I read.

Comment: That seems like an overly ambitious step up in difficulty to me. The intro to _Noncommutative Geometry_ is comparatively friendly, though the text blithely assumes expert knowledge in functional analysis, differential geometry, algebraic topology, algebraic K-theory, ....